# Lubuntu + Virtual Box. Black screen after login

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, display-settings

I Installed Lubuntu 18 on Virtual Box 5.2.22.

Changed Display Resolution in Preferences -> Monitor Settings.

Then I restarted Lubuntu.

Lubuntu login menu displayed, but after login there is only the black screen.

If I do nothing for some time and the system is locked, login menu is displayed.

So I can see only the login menu and after login there is the black screen.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:
1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get a command prompt.
2. login using your id
3. enter

`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop lightdm lubuntu-default-settings xorg lubuntu-core`
and then reboot:
`sudo shutdown now -r`

Comment: get an error "unable to locate package default-settings"

Comment: @kostepanych oops, I mean ```lubuntu-default-settings```

Answer (score 1):

in my case disabling 3d acceleration in VirtualBox 6.1 settings helped
[image]

Comment: Fixed it for me. Lubuntu 20.04 and Virtualbox 6.1.26